# proof injectivity of $\phi:\mathbb{C}[t]\rightarrow A:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Looking the quotient ring $A:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$,
we define a homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{C}[t]\rightarrow A$ with $t \mapsto \bar{x}+\bar{y}$, where $R:=\operatorname{Im} (\phi)$.

We've said in the classes that $\phi$ is injective because when we pick up 
$f(t)\in \mathbb{C}[t]$ such that $\phi(f(t))=f(\bar x+\bar y)=0$ in $A$, then there is $g(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]:f(x,y)=g(x,y)(xy-1)$.

Now we were said that when $f(x,y)$ has maximal $y$-degree $m$, then this would be contradiction because $g(x,y)$ is also of $y$-degree $m$ and $g(x,y)(xy-1)$ is of maximal $y$-degree $m+1$. So $g(x,y)=0$.

I don't understand  this argumentation. Can't we elect a $g(x,y)$  with degree $m-1$, so that everything is fine? And why because of injectivity of $\phi$  it finally follows  that $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[t]$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by maximal degree?

Comment: degree of a polynomial 'not more than' $m$

Comment: You probably wanted to write $f(x+y)=g(x,y)(xy-1)$.

Comment: If $\deg f=m$ then expanding $(x+y)^m$ one gets $x^m$ in the left hand side, while in the right hand side this has to occur in $g(x,y)$. But after multiplying by $xy$ this yields $x^my$ which is not in $f(x+y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $f(x,y)=a_0+a_1(x+y)+...+a_m(x+y)^m=g(x,y)(xy-1)=g(x,y)xy-g(x,y)$ it results that $g(x,y)$ has a monomial of the form $a_mx^m$, this implies that $-a_mx^mxy$ is in $g(x,y)(xy-1)$ impossible since the degree of $g(x,y)(xy-1)$ is $m$.

Comment: Why it results that $g(x,y)$ has  monomial $a_m x^m$?

Comment: identify the coefficients of $f(x+y)$ and $g(x,y)(xy-1)=xyg(x,y)-g(x,y)$.